# GDB: dump arguments to all calls of a specific function

Tags: c, gdb, profiling

I need to profile the values passed as arguments to the standard C library function sqrt() in my program.

The trivial way is to insert code to dump these values to a file before the actual call to sqrt() (e.g. a simple fprintf()). However, if sqrt() is called from inside a library, or if it is called from multiple locations, the task can become hard.

Is there a way to automatically do this in GDB or in some other debugging tool?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it can be done.  There is an easy way and a hard way.

The easy way is if you have debuginfo for `sqrt`.  Most distros make this available; e.g., for Fedora you can use `debuginfo-install` to install it.

In this case, find the function in question, set a breakpoint on it, and have the breakpoint commands print the arguments:

```
break sqrt
commands
  silent
  info args
  cont
end
```

If you have a new enough gdb, and you know the names of the arguments, you can use the `dprintf` command instead.  This will give you nicer formatting and not interact badly with other debugging commands like `next`.

The hard way is if you don't have debug info.  In this case you need to know the platform ABI.  Then you can still set the breakpoint, and then print the appropriate registers or dump the appropriate memory, depending on how the arguments are passed.

Yet another way is to use SystemTap.  This is a pretty good tool for this kind of tracing.

Comment: Please add example with dprintf

Comment: @diralik I'm not sure that `info args` can be passed to dprintf as a parameter